# How to list all files in all weekly directories in a tree?

Tags: php

I have a folder tree structure like

```
arndell
\_databases
  \_daily
  \_weekly
claremont
\_databases
  \_daily
  \_weekly
monte
\_databases
  \_daily
  \_weekly
```

where there could be added new top folder at any time.

I am after **all files in daily and weekly directories**. I wonder if there is a way how to get all files in all weekly directories using **one php command** or **call a unix command** from php or I have to crawl the structure one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PHP Command - not 1 line solution...

look at [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), can make it recursive.

#### Unix Command - one line solution!

- dirs & files: `find /path/*/weekly/*`
- files onlye: `find /path/*/weekly/* -type f`

use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or `` to get command output into your PHP script.

Comment: Find is tooooooooo sloooooooooow. `ls ./*/*/weekly` is the way.

Comment: glad you got a solution. For some reason I thought you need output of paths that can be put into php array for processing. `ls ./*/weekly/*` will give multiline delimited output thats will require parsing to work with. Also, `find` works fast when it knows the path, like in your case.

Comment: `find . -name 'weekly' | xargs ls` took about 30 mins to finish. While  ls only a sec.